# Crystal Reports IF Statement/ Formula / Date Qestion

Tags: sql, date, if-statement, crystal-reports

I'm working with Crystal Reports editor and came across the following issue: what I have are 2 date fields & I would like the records to change the colour:

**IF DateField1 value is 7 days or less of DateField2 then crRed else crBlack**

For example: if DateField1 value is 01/01/2020 and the DateField2 value is 06/01/2020 then the record colour would change to red. If however, we've had something like 01/01/2020 and 01/02/2020 then the record font colour would remain black.

I am unable to work out how to get the extra 7 days off the DateField2. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried DATEDIFF(DAY, '2020-01-01' ,  '2020-02-01')?

Comment: Hi, I'm not entirely sure how to use the DATEDIFF in an IF statement with the above problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked this out using the DATEDIFF as advised by Sandeep!

> ```
> IF DATEDIFF ("d",{DATEFIELD1} ,{DATEFIELD2}) <= 7 then crRed else
> crBlack
> ```